# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /app_path/public/10205/18_barcode.png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, barcode

I am using **barby** gem to generate the bar codes. I am getting this error on this type of strings i-e "**105811/18**". when I use this string like "**105811_18**" or "**105811-18**" it works fine and generate the barcode successfully but generating error on **slash keyword**, and pointing error on second last line of my method. "**File.open(file_path, 'wb') { |f| f.write output }**" Thanks for your help in advance.

```
require 'barby'
require 'barby/barcode/code_128'
require 'barby/outputter/png_outputter'


def self.get_bar_code(medical_record_no)
 barcode_digits = medical_record_no.rjust(13, '0')
 barcode = Barby::Code128.new(barcode_digits)
 output = Barby::PngOutputter.new(barcode).to_png
 file_path = File.join(Rails.root, 'public', "#{medical_record_no}_barcode.png")
 File.open(file_path, 'wb') { |f| f.write output }
 return barcode_digits
end
```

Comment: What platform are you running on? `/` is a common path separator on many platforms, so I believe what's happening is that your string is being interpreted as a directory named `105811` and a file named `18`. If `/` characters are common in your input, you should probably convert them to something else before attempting to create the file.

Comment: it makes sense. Thanks a lot @Brian